# Find an equation to the tangent plane and normal line to the surface $3xyz - (z^3) = 1$ at the point $(0,1,-1)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

To the get the equation of a plane, I would need the equations of two lines that lie on the plane. How would I obtain these?

Comment: It's easier here to go directly for a normal vector and a point in the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient of a function is perpendicular to the level curves. So in your case, you can imagine a function of three variables $$F(x,y,z)=3xyz-z^3$$ and your surface is the level curve $$F(x,y,z)=1$$

Since the gradient points in the direction perpendicular to the surface, you can create an equation for the normal line going through a point on the surface. To create the equation of a plane, you only need a normal and a point in the plane. Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: I can definitely obtain the gradient, and a point is already given, so I will now attempt a solution.

Comment: If you know $n$ is a perpendicular vector to a surface at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ then the line is $(x-x_0)/n_1=(y-y_0)/n_2=(z-z_0)/n_3$, with the agreement that if for instance $n_1 =0 $ then it forces $x-x_0=0$.

The plane's equation is $\{(x,y,z) | \ (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) \cdot n =0 \} .$

Comment: The gradient of the function at any point is perpendicular to its tangent line/plane. So I used the gradient at (0,1,-1) as my normal. An equation of the tangent plane is therefore: -3x -3(z+1) = 0, correct?

Comment: @ChristianChimezie I believe your answer is correct.

Comment: No! $1(y-y_0)+ (-1)(z-z_0)=0$ will be your tangent plane.

Comment: @Behnam but the gradient is $<3yz, 3xz, 3xy - 3z^2>$. Plugging in $(x,y,z)=(0,1,-1)$ yields $<-3, 0, -3>$. So the tangent plane is $<-3, 0, -3>\cdot <x-0, y-1, z+1>=0$. and that becomes $-3x - 3(z+1)=0$

Comment: @ChristianChimezie Also, you can divide both sides by -3 to make the equation simpler: $x+z+1=0$

Comment: You're right. I thought you said gradient WAS (0,1,-1). I did not compute the gradient on my own. Then... Yes, you've got a tangent plane.